# what query is executed on a listbox.requery

Tags: ms-access, vba

when i am running the following code:

```
listbox1.requery
```

which query is this going to run? where can i edit this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That causes the RowSource property in the ListBox to be re-queried.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're requerying the recordset returned by the listbox's rowsource, not the rowsource itself, which is just a string value.